# Non conflicting debug and prod version

Tags: android, debugging, build, production

I have my app published to the store and I keep it on my phone for reference. When pushing a debug build I need to uninstall first the store version which is quite annoying. Is there a way for me that the debug version of my app has a different name and doesn't conflict with the prod version so that I could have both of them of my phone?

Thanks

Comment: With Android Studio and Gradle, this isn't too difficult. Check this out: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Gradle flavors for this. See this [post](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_Gradle_Build_Variants_Example) or [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants). Official Android Studio guide: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

Comment: If I'm reading correctly, I just had two flavors with two application id and I'm good. Awesome I thought I have to change the package name